# Regex - Words containing multiple underscores

Tags: java, regex, identifier, lexer

I'm making a Lexer, and have chosen to use Regex to split my tokens.

I'm working on all different tokens, except the one that really bugs me is **words and identifiers**.

You see, the rules I have in place are the following:

- Words cannot start with or end with an underscore.
- Words can be one or more characters in length.
- Underscores can only be used **between** letters, and can appear multiple times.

Example of what I want:

```
_foo         <- Invalid.
foo_         <- Invalid.
_foo_        <- Invalid.
foo_foo      <- Valid.
foo_foo_foo  <- Valid.
foo_foo_     <- Partially Valid. Only "foo_foo" should be picked up.
_foo_foo     <- Partially Valid. Only "foo_foo" should be picked up.
```

I'm getting close, as this is what I currently have:

`([a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+)`

Except, it only detects the first occurence of an underscore. I want all of them.

**Personal Request:**

I would rather the answer be contained inside of a single group, as I have structured my tokeniser around them, except I would be more than happy to change my design if you can think of a better way of handling it. This is what I currently use:

```
private void tokenise(String regex, String[] data) {
    Set<String> tokens = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    // First pass. Uses regular expressions to split data and catalog token types.
    for (String line : data) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            for (int i = 1; i < matcher.groupCount() + 1; i++) {
                if (matcher.group(i) != null) {
                    switch(i) {
                    case (1):
                        // Example group.
                        // Normally I would structure like:
                        // 0: Identifiers
                        // 1: Strings
                        // 2-?: So on so forth.
                        tokens.add("FOO:" + matcher.group());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `([a-zA-Z]+(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)*)`

The first part of the pattern, `[a-zA-Z]+`, matches one or more letters.
The second part of the pattern, `(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)`, matches an undescore if it is followed by one or more letters.
The `*` at the end means the second part can be repeated zero or more times.
The `(?: )` is like plain `()`, but doesn't return the matched group.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thankyou. Can you please explain what you did differently to me?

Comment: If you do not use `String#matches()`, or you want to find words, not identifiers in a larger text, this regex will also match `foo` in `_foo`. Not sure it is expected.

Comment: @frayment  The first part of the pattern, `[a-zA-Z]+`, matches one or more letters.  The second part of the pattern, `(?:_[a-zA-Z]+)`, matches an undescore if it is followed by one or more letters.  The * at the end means the second part can be repeated zero or more times.  The `(?:   )` is like plain `()`, but doesn't return the matched group.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you look at the rules in the question, that should be fine. Unless your talking about `foo_**foo**` being captured, then yes, thats not expected.

Comment: @frayment: *`_foo`         <- Invalid.* Now, the [regex demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/vA2vJ4/1). Is it expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, thats fine. It ignores the underscore like expected. What I'm doing is, anything not detected gets flushed into a "Syntax Error" capture group.